Flutter version 3.27.0 throws exception - MissingPluginexception and PlatformException for Android
I am facing a few errors with the latest version of Flutter(3.27.0). A lot of the packages that I have used within the app, arre working fine on iOS but not on Android. They usually throw exceptions like MissingPluginImplementation(No implementation found for method on channel) or PlatformException(Unable to establish connection on channel).
I have tried the usual stuff - Upgrading all packages -> flutter clean -> flutter pub cache clean -> flutter run.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.
